# How do I loop into my Web scraper better?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a websites search page by making the scraper scrape links of each item on the page, after which the scraped links is parsed again and certain information is scraped from this links too. The issue I have rn is if the initial links have been scraped I want to loop through each of this links and scrape data from them but it's currently only scraping for the first value in the list of links. I guess the problem is with my for loop.

Here's my current code.

```
productLinks = []
carMake = [] 


url = "https://buy.cars45.com/cars"
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}


searchResults = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(searchResults.text, "html.parser")

searchlinks = soup.find_all('div', class_='product_box')

for i in searchlinks:
    a = i.find('a').get('href')
    if a:
        productLinks.append(a)
#         print(a)
    else:
        productLinks.append('kNone')


for j in productLinks:
    productPage = requests.get(j, headers=headers)
     soup2 = BeautifulSoup(productPage.text, "html.parser")

     details = soup2.find_all('span', class_='float-right')

     make = details[0].text
     carName.append(make)
```

But it just returns the first car repeated many times as output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this should work

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url ='https://www.lbbusinessjournal.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

links = []

for post in soup.find_all(['h3', 'li'], class_=['entry-title td-module-title', 'menu-item']):
  link = post.find('a')
  if link:
      link = link.get('href')
      links.append(link)
      print(len(link))
      print(link)

for i in links:
  r2 = requests.get(i)
  soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')

  for post1 in soup1.find_all('h3', class_='entry-title td-module-title'):
      link1 = post1.find('a')
      if link1: 
          print(link1.text)
```

When i ran your code it gave some errors, so if that was your problem, 
you should check if `post1.find('a')` returned `None`. This can happen if `post1` doesn't include an `<a>` tag.

Comment: @user8173388 Again you call `i.find('a').get('href')`, though `i.find('a')` can default to `None` when `a` is not contained in the html code you are parsing. As `None` does not have an attribute named `get`, this will again result in an Exception. Can you explain what specifically about the above code i posted did not work for you?